# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE creating new records

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I am having problems with the following code, it seems to work and creates the records just fine, the problem is each time I hit submit, instead of it updating the record it just creates a new one. If I turn off auto incremental for the primary key it updates the record just fine but then doesn't create any new ones, it seems either one or the other :-S

```
<?php
 $query = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO hqfjt_chronoforms_data_emailform 
   (cf_id,cf_uid,emailformname,datesent)
  VALUES
   ('$_POST[cf_id]','$_POST[cf_uid]','$_POST[emailformname]','$_POST[datesent]')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   datesent='$_POST[datesent]';
 ") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

Comment: What are the `unique` or `primary key` fields in your database?

Comment: Shouldn't **$_POST[datesent]** be something like **$_POST['datesent']**?

Comment: cf_id is the primary key, the other fields are just fields that are pulled in through the session data and are only used when the record is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you already try to echo your query string? guess the variable replacement inside it is wrong. try something like that for debugging:

```
<?php
 $sql = "INSERT INTO hqfjt_chronoforms_data_emailform 
   (cf_id,cf_uid,emailformname,datesent)
  VALUES
   ('{$_POST['cf_id']}','{$_POST['cf_uid']}','{$_POST['emailformname']}','{$_POST['datesent']}')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   datesent='{$_POST['datesent']}'";
 echo $sql; // for debugging
 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

Note the corrected variable names above. (curly braces around it, quotes around the array index)

Comment: INSERT INTO hqfjt_chronoforms_data_emailform (cf_id,cf_uid,emailformname,datesent) VALUES ('','8d50cf1becab8c90ec0e387a746da8c3','Merry Christmas','30-12-2011') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datesent='30-12-2011'

Comment: there you have it: the post var `cf_id` is empty. check why its not posted on the other side of the POST. when a auto_increment field is INSERTed empty or NULL, a new auto incremented value is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine it's the problem, but does the same thing happen when you cast the ID to an `int` and leave out the quotes?

```
<?php
 $query = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO hqfjt_chronoforms_data_emailform 
   (cf_id,cf_uid,emailformname,datesent)
  VALUES
   (" . (int) $_POST['cf_id'] . ",'$_POST[cf_uid]','$_POST[emailformname]','$_POST[datesent]')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   datesent='$_POST[datesent]';
 ") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

By the way, you really shouldn't use your `$_POST` variables in your query without `mysql_real_escape_string` or better yet, use prepared statements (PDO or mysqli).

Comment: This doesnt seem to make any difference, it still creates a new record with a different cf_id, thanks for the advice with the POST, I have just removed everything I can just for debugging as I wasnt sure what was causing this.